# Canvas in v-html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Any idea why

```
<div v-html="aCanvasElementGeneratedFromCode.outerHTML"/>
```

shows a blank canvas (with correct width and height) - while

```
<img :src="aCanvasElementGeneratedFromCode.toDataURL()"/>
```

works just fine and shows the image?

https://jsfiddle.net/madfv7gw/

Comment: Why shouldn't it? outerHTML is `<canvas>`. It's literally a blank canvas.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, but why is the context not drawn?

Comment: Because you basically insert `<canvas></canvas>` HTML this way. It's totally unrelated to aCanvasElementGeneratedFromCode element and its context.